# CSS only lightbox- Click to close & zoom

Tags: css, lightbox

I'm trying to create a versitile (for mobile, desktops and tablets) lightbox pop-up. I'm inputting it through Gravityforms, so the link itself can only be HTML.

This code works- but it's a little messy. It has to be gallery, and text, which I've achieved already. I'm using wordpress 4.0 so if there's a better plugin solution I'm open to it.

- A nice transition when opening
- Resize to fit mobile/smaller screens
- Click background to close

There will be **multiple galleries on one page**.

My code so far

```
       #gallery .item a { 
    overflow: hidden;
    }

#gallery .item a img {
    height: 100%; 
    align-self: center;
    }

.lightbox {
    /** Hide the lightbox */
    display: none;

    /** Apply basic lightbox styling */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color:#333333;
    }

.lightbox:target {
    /** Show lightbox when it is target */
    display: block;
    outline: none;
}

.lightbox .box {
    width: -webkit-min-content;
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: min-content;
    min-width:500px;
    margin: 2% auto;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 26px -3px #777777; 
    }

.lightbox .title {
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 10px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px #ccc solid;
    font-size:22px;
    }

.lightbox .content {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    }


.lightbox .content .desc {
    z-index:99;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 0 4px 0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);

    color:#fff;
    font-size:17px;
    opacity:0.75;
    transition: opacity ease-in-out 0.5s;
    }   

.lightbox .content:hover .desc  {
    opacity:0.8;
}

.lightbox .next,
.lightbox .prev,
.lightbox .close {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:22px;
    color:#858585;
    }

.prev {
    float:left;
    }

.next, .close {
    float:right;
    }

    .clear {
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        }
```

I think this is the kind of transition I want:

```
    html { min-height: 100%; position: relative; }
body { margin: 0; height: 100%; margin-right: 2em;  background: #110; }
dl { float: left; }
dd a { 
  background: #fff; display: inline-block;
transition: 4s box-shadow ease-in;
```

A zoom feature would be great too, (ie from within the lightbox) but I'm unsure that's possible.

Any help is much appreciated

My latest JSFiddle [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdmx6x4a/8/)

Comment: Thanks Peter- here's a fiddle [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdmx6x4a/7/)

Answer (score 1):

- A nice transition when opening.
  *Use CSS `transition`*
- Resize to fit mobile/smaller screens
   *Use `max-width: 100%`
  You might want to experiment with the length of the description in `.desc` as it seems to be too long for the width of a mobile screen*
- Click background to close.
   *I think this can be achieved using javascript.*

---

Check out the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wkcyskoj/4/)** here.

---

Comment: I don't quite follow- but thansk for looking. I looked at your fiddle and it looks the same.

This [example link](http://codepen.io/gschier/pen/HCoqh) has no JS but has the background click to exit. 
I'm almost there- the background does not fade and the header stays on top. I would like the text/image to be responsive to the width. Can anyone help me with these?

Comment: In my fiddle, the box *fades in* as you wanted a transition to take place instead of *just appearing*. I have made it responsive too, try resizing the result portion and see it respond to the width. Clicking the background to close would be possible if you use javascript.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to exaggerate the transition for you to see.

Comment: Ah thankyou I can now see how it is working. Lastly I'm looking for the right javascript to make my lightbox close when clicking the background. Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated the fiddle. But I would seriously recommend you optimise your code. It has become a lot messier than it should be. If you are using javascript, it will be a lot easier to listen to click event rather than using `:target` in your CSS.

Comment: Appreciate that- I might look for another solution like FancyBox if I can figure out jquery